# How to update an appended value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Guys I have an input text and when I start typing, it counts how many letters I am using. But when I clear the input value, I can't change letter counter. How can I get it?
Thanks in advance.
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/28bs18gq/1/)

```js
function count_letter() {
  var len = $("#area").val().length;
  $('#counter').append(len);
}
  
$('#area').bind('keyup', function() {
  $('#counter').html('');
  count_letter();
});
  
$('#clear-value').click(function(){
  $("#area").val(" ");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="area"><br>
<div id="counter"></div><br>

<button id="clear-value">
Clear value
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `#clear-value` event handler, add:

```
$('#counter').empty();
```

Which will clear the `#counter` element.

```js
  function count_letter() {
    var len = $("#area").val().length;
    $('#counter').append(len);
  }

  $(function() {
    $('#area').bind('keyup', function() {
      $('#counter').html('');
      count_letter();
    });

    $('#clear-value').click(function(){
      $("#area").val("");
      $('#counter').empty(); //<<<-----
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="area"><br>
<div id="counter"></div><br>

<button id="clear-value">
Clear value
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call your count_letter function when you clear the input value :

```
$('#clear-value').click(function(){
    $("#area").val(" ");
    $('#counter').html('');
    count_letter();
});
```

Comment: I add $('#counter').html(''); (that you should put in your count_letter function) on your jsfiddle and it worked good, did you click the run button on jsfiddle after making the change ?

Comment: Because you set the val to " ", you should set it to ""

Answer (score 0):

Cleear your counter on click of clear value button.
See below in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/28bs18gq/2/

```
function count_letter() {
    var len = $("#area").val().length;
    $('#counter').append(len);
    }

  $('#area').bind('keyup', function() {
    $('#counter').html('');
    count_letter();
  });

  $('#clear-value').click(function(){
  $("#area").val(" ");
    $('#counter').html('');
  });
```